# Integral of cosine gives divide by zero?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

So I have an integral that I know the answer to, but can't seem to prove because a divide by zero occurs when evaluating.
$$I=\int_{0}^{L}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)dx,\ \ \ n \in \mathbb{N}$$
I tried to evaluate the integral using the fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$I=\left[\frac{L}{n\pi}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)\right]_0^L=\frac{L}{n\pi}\sin\left(n\pi\right)-\frac{L}{n\pi}\sin(0)=L\ \mathrm{sinc}(n\pi)-\frac{0}{n\pi}$$
The problem arises when $n=0$. It is obvious the answer is $L$, since the cosine just becomes $1$ and the integral integrates from $0$ to $L$. However second term becomes $\frac{0}{0}$, and I don't know how to deal with it. If I were to take the limit as $n$ approaches $0$ it would be fine, but in this case $n$ is a constant that can only be a natural number.

Can anyone help me rationalise why in this case $\frac{0}{0}=0$?

Comment: There is not much to rationalise. The evaluation is obviously is valid only for $n\neq 0$.

Comment: You never reach to $\frac{0}{0}$. The correct procedure goes like this:
$I=\left[\frac{L}{n\pi}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)\right]_0^L$ when $n\ne 0$, etc.
And do the case $n=0$ separately.

Comment: @AmateurDotCounter That's a neat trick! I guess what most people have answered here is that in the case of $n=0$ a different approach is necessary because the difference of antiderivatives is not valid.

Comment: @nanocat On closer inspection, my trig trick seemed to be more handwavy and less rigorous than I'd have liked.  However, a different tactic would be to integrate from $aL$ to $L$ (for $0<a<<1$) and take the limit toward zero.

Answer (score 1):

You say that don't want to take the limit as $ n \to 0 $ because $ n $ needs to be a natural number.  But (except for the $ n \in \mathbb N $ on the side), nothing that you wrote requires this.  So you can argue that the value of the integral is $ L \operatorname { sinc } ( n \pi ) $ whenever $ n \ne 0 $, so it makes sense that the value is $ L \operatorname { sinc } ( 0 \pi ) = L $ when $ n = 0 $.

Now, if you want to make a proof out of this, you need an argument that the entire expression is continuous in $ n $.  This requires checking that the limit $ \cos ( n \pi x / L ) \to \cos ( 0 \pi x / L ) $ as $ n \to 0 $ converges uniformly (or finding some other theorem that allows you to move a limit inside an integral).  So it's easier just to work out the $ n = 0 $ case separately, and then you can see if that agrees with the limit of the $ n \ne 0 $ results.  Still, the fact is that they do agree.

Interestingly, if you do require $ n $ to be an integer, then you can simplify $ L \operatorname { sinc } ( n \pi ) $ to $ 0 $ whenever $ n \ne 0 $.  So we get that the integral is $ 0 $ whenver $ n $ is a nonzero integer but $ L $ when $ n $ is zero.  Now it does *not* work to find the value when $ n = 0 $ by taking a limit, but that makes sense since we're only looking at integer values of $ n $ this time.  By allowing non-integer values of $ n $ as well, the limit makes sense again, and in fact gives the correct answer.